# Separate MIDI song events from initial setup events

Tags: java, midi

I am playing a MIDI song using a Java [Sequencer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/Sequencer.html).  The song is designed to be looped continuously, which I can do easily with
`sequencer.setLoopCount(Sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY)`
When played through the internal (soundcard) synthesizer this works fine and (with the addition of a [dummy event](http://www.jsresources.org/faq_midi.html#sequence_clipped) if necessary) the loop timing is spot on.

However when played through an external (USB or serial) synth there is a noticeable gap in the output at the point where it loops around.  This is explained by the fact that there are many setup events at the start of the .mid file that take some time to be sent over the serial line.

What I would like to try is isolating the one-time setup events into their own [`Sequence`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/Sequence.html) which is sent to the device once when the song is loaded but kept out of the main (looped) `Sequence`.

**Is there a simple algorithm (or library function) that can distinguish the two kinds of event?**

It would need to provide for:

- [Registered parameter](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php#3a) changes, which are sent as a group of related messages.
- Occasionally channel program changes are sent in the middle of a track (and must be part of the looped sequence), but where the same program is kept throughout the song (the majority of cases) the program change should be part of the setup sequence.  The same applies to tempo changes.

Comment: *This is explained by the fact that there are many setup events at the start of the .mid file that take some time to be sent over the serial line* - is this an assumption or guestimation or do you have a source (techincal article or debugging output) to demonstrate it?

Comment: @Charles Goodwin, no I tested this by manually removing events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at javax.sound.midi. Sequence consists of Tracks. Tracks contain MidiEvents. MidiEvents are a combination of a timestamp and a MidiMessage.

MidiMessage has subclasses ShortMessage, MetaMessage and SysexMessage.

Most probably filtering out SysexMessages at tick 0 (MidiEvent.getTick() == 0) will do the trick. If not, then try filtering also the MetaMessages at the tick 0. Note information, program changes etc are done via ShortMessages, do not filter those.

```
for each track in sequence {
  for all midievents in track at tick 0 {
    remove from track if instanceof SysexMessage or MetaMessage
  }
}
```

The other part is to create the initialization Sequence. Just create Sequence with same divisionType and resolution. One track is enough, you can add all events removed from the looping Sequence to a single Track in the initialization Sequence.

Comment: The MetaMessages are not part of the problem because they are never sent over the wire.